# How can rename the root node of xml with xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

How can rename with xquery

That-->

```
<TTABLA xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2013-04-01T11:01:37">
<tabla>
    <cod>2</cod>
</tabla>
</TCLIENTS>
```

To -->

```
 <tablas>
 <tabla>
    <cod>2</cod>
 </tabla>
 </tablas>
```

I tried with that(but don't work):

```
update rename root(doc('/db/data/tablas.xml')//TTABLA ) as "tablas"
```

Help please.

Comment: Don't tell us that something didn't work. Tell us how it failed.

Comment: I tried that: update rename doc('/db/data/tablas.xml')/TTABLA as "tablas" and the error it's "No previous sibling for the old child" thanks

Comment: I don't know where your update syntax comes from. With Saxon XQuery Update I tried `rename node /TTABLA as "tablas"` and it worked fine - though it does retain the namespace and attribute on the root element which you didn't ask for.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should work:

```
<tablas>{//tabla}</tablas>
```